# Stuck with the problem of Feynman parameters

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I'm a student of physics and stuck with the following mathematical step involving Feynman parameters. One can show that $$\frac{1}{ABC}=2\int\limits_{0}^{1}dx \int\limits_{0}^{1-x}dy\frac{1}{[Ax+By+C(1-x-y)]^3}$$ where $A,B,C$ are constants. However, I cannot deduce the formula $$\frac{1}{ABC}=\int\limits_{0}^{1}dx \int\limits_{0}^{1}dy\frac{2y}{[\{Ax+B(1-x)\}y+C(1-y)]^3}$$ starting from the first or by any other means. The last expression is given at Yndurain's book on Quantum Chromodynamics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $A, B, C >0$.

If $A\neq B$ then
\begin{equation*}
\int\dfrac{2y}{\left[(Ax+B(1-x))y+C(1-y)\right]^3}\, dx = \dfrac{-1}{(A-B)\left[(A-B)xy+(B-C)y+C\right]^2}
\end{equation*}
If we proceed in this way the solution will split up into a lot of cases where $A\neq B$ is the first one. Instead we restart and make the substituions $u = \dfrac{1}{x}-1$ and $v = \dfrac{1}{y}-1$. Then
\begin{gather*}
\int_{0}^{1}\,dx\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{2y}{\left[(Ax+B(1-x))y+C(1-y)\right]^3}\, dy = \int_{0}^{\infty}\,du\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{2(u+1)}{(A+Bu+C(u+1)v)^3}\, dv=\\[2ex]
\int_{0}^{\infty}\,du\left[\dfrac{-1}{C(A+Bu+C(u+1)v)^2}\right]_{0}^{\infty} = \int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{C(A+Bu)^2}\, du = \left[\dfrac{-1}{BC(A+Bu)}\right]_{0}^{\infty} = \dfrac{1}{ABC}.
\end{gather*}